# Can DependencyProperties be overriden?

Tags: wpf, controls

I try to create a certain type of ListView in WPF and therefore I created my own control that inherits from `ListView`.

Is it possible to override the default `ItemsSource` property of `ListView` and make sure that the object that is put into `ItemsSource` in my very own control is of a certain type or implements a certain interface? At best the developer gets a red squiggly line at design time and an error message in the tool tip that the object has to implement...

If that's not possible and I have to create my own property, is it possible to prevent developers to use the still existing `ItemsSource` property and tell them to use my property instead?

Is it possible to hook into the `PropertyChangedCallback` of an inherited property (like `ItemsSource`) and do some of my own stuff there?

Comment: Take a look at DependencyProperty.OverrideMetadata. IMO changing the semantics of the ItemsSource property is a bad idea. If you really need to have a list control that only accepts a certain item type, do not derive from ListBox at all.

Comment: I'll have a look at that, thank you.